# Ícono de exportar no se muestra correctamente en una gráfica de Highcharts

Tags: javascript, html, html5, highcharts

Estoy experimentando un error muy raro y es que tengo en una página 3 gráficas, de las cuales 2 gráficas se muestran correctamente con su ícono de exportar [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí] respectivamente.

Sin embargo, una de las gráficas no muestra dicho ícono. Muestro el código que tengo para construirla:

HTML

```
<figure class="highcharts-figure">
  <div style="height:600px !important;" id="container-varios"></div>
</figure>
```

Javascript

```
Highcharts.chart('container-varios', {
  chart: {
      type: 'area'
  },
  credits: { enabled: false },
  legend:{
      verticalAlign:'top',
      align : 'left',
      useHTML: true,
  },
  accessibility: {
      description: ''
  },
  title: {
      text: ''
  },
  subtitle: {
      text: ''
  },
  xAxis: {
      categories: dataContent.rango_fechas
  },
  yAxis: {
      title: {
          text: ''
      },
      labels: {
          formatter: function () {
              return this.value + '';
          }
      }
  },

  exporting: {
      buttons: {

      }
  },

    series: [

      {
          name: 'Total cursos',
          data: [],
          events: {
              legendItemClick: function (e) {
                  e.preventDefault();
              }
          },
      },

      {
          name: 'Total views',
          marker: {
              symbol: 'url(assets/img/iconogris.png)'
          },
          data: dataContent.total_views,
          color : "#929292",
          events: {
              legendItemClick: function (e) {
                  e.preventDefault();
              }
          },
      },

      {
          name: 'Total Usuarios',
          marker: {
              symbol: 'url(assets/img/iconogrisclaro.png)'
          },
          data: dataContent.totales_suscritos_profesor,
          //data: default_values2,
          color : "#5E5E5E",
          events: {
              legendItemClick: function (e) {
                  e.preventDefault();
              }
          },

      },
      {
          name: 'Total usuarios suscritos <br> a la playlist',
          data: dataContent.total_usuarios_suscritos_playlist,
          events: {
              legendItemClick: function (e) {
                  e.preventDefault();
              }
          },
      },

      {
          name: 'Valoración media',
          data: [],
          events: {
              legendItemClick: function (e) {
                  e.preventDefault();
              }
          },
      },

      {
          name: 'Total valoraciones',
          data: [],
          events: {
              legendItemClick: function (e) {
                  e.preventDefault();
              }
          },
      },

    ]
});
```

Además, agregué las siguientes librerías correspondientes para exportar

```
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/series-label.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/offline-exporting.js"></script>

<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/exporting.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/export-data.js"></script>
```

Me gustaría volver a aclarar que omití la parte donde construyo dos gráficas en el mismo documento y que éstas sí se muestran correctamente con su ícono de exportar, sin embargo, como comenté antes, esta gráfica en particular no tiene el ícono respectivamente a pesar de que parece estar configurada correctamente (dejo este screenshot para que vean cómo se muestran estas tres gráficas).

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: A mi me paso hace poco, pero era por no estar trabajando con una versión más actual de Highcharts

Answer (score 0):

He subido tu ejemplo a un server compartido para que veas el resultado, y no encuentro error en lo que estas mostrando, lo más probable es que sea un CSS (que sobre-escribe) de ese gráfico. Para mí son las leyendas que pueden estar por encima del botón pero el botón debe estar ahí. Deberías hacer un inspect del HTML y ver si el botón está o no ahí. Y luego, quitar algunas leyendas (que son 6) como 2 y ver si aún asi no se muestra.
https://jsfiddle.net/670b1La3/

Saludos Cordiales

Comment: Hola. Gracias por tu respuesta. Las propiedades rango_fechas, total_views, y totales_suscritos_profesor son un array de elementos, por ejemplo el númeor de elementos de cada uno podrían ser 5 elementos, no son strings debido a que en el eje x estoy dibujando un desglose de fechas (como viene en la imagen que adjunté) Ejemplo, rango_fechas = ["01/DIC/2020","02/DIC/2020","'03/DIC/2020","04/DIC/2020","05/DIC/2020"]

Comment: el problema estaba en la propiedad "color" de cada "series" de la gráfica, quitando eso ya se ve el ícono, gracias